# MVC ASP C# My DeviceID is not displaying on my views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Im having alot of trouble trying to get my UserID and DeviceID ( a part of two separate models) to display on one of my Index views. Im building a website that allows where by creating a User(AKA Patient) you can add a Device that can be associated with that user.  I am doing this through dropdowns of the list of seeded devices.  While the dropdown list shows the devices, it does not update the index with the selected device.

My Aim is to get the DeviceID & Name to correctly display on my User(AKA Patient) Index View. Also when i Create and Edit users i want the dropdowns to update the User information on the Patient(User) Index View.

**PatientController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using FaceToFace.Model;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace FaceToFaceWebsite.Controllers
{
    public class PatientController : Controller
    {
        private F2FData db = new F2FData();

        //
        // GET: /Patient/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            return View(db.Users.ToList());
        }

        //
        // GET: /Patient/Details/5

        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            User user = db.Users.Find(id);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(user);
        }


        // GET: /Patient/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {

            ViewBag.DeviceID = new SelectList(db.Devices, "DeviceID", "Name");
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Patient/Create

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "UserID,CodeName,UseBriefInstructions")] User user, Device device)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //db.Devices = user.Device.DeviceID;
                db.Users.Add(user);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.DeviceID = new SelectList(db.Devices, "DeviceID", "Name", user.Device.DeviceID);
            return View(user);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Patient/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            User user = db.Users.Find(id);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            //removed   user.Device.DeviceID
            ViewBag.DeviceID = new SelectList(db.Devices, "DeviceID", "Name");
            return View(user);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Patient/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "UserID,CodeName,UseBriefInstructions")] User user)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.DeviceID = new SelectList(db.Devices, "DeviceID", "Name", user.Device.DeviceID);
            return View(user);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Patient/Delete/5

        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            User user = db.Users.Find(id);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(user);

        }

        //
        // POST: /Patient/Delete/5

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            User user = db.Users.Find(id);
            db.Users.Remove(user);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

**User.cs (Model)**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FaceToFace.Model
{
    public class User
    {

        public int UserID { get; set; }

        public string CodeName { get; set; }

        public bool UseBriefInstructions { get; set; }

        public Device Device { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Device.cs (Model)**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FaceToFace.Model
{
    public class Device
    {
        public int DeviceID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Views/Patient/Index.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<FaceToFace.Model.User>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Your Patients</h2>

Showing @Model.Count() users

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Add New User", "Create")
</p>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CodeName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Device.Name)*@Device
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Device.DeviceID)
        </th>

    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CodeName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Device.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Device.DeviceID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.UserID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.UserID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.UserID })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

**Views/Patient/Create.cshtml**

```
    @model FaceToFace.Model.User

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    }

    <h2>Create</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <fieldset>
            <legend>User</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CodeName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CodeName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CodeName)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Device.Name, "Device")
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownList("DeviceID", String.Empty)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UseBriefInstructions)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UseBriefInstructions)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UseBriefInstructions)
            </div>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    }

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

**Views/Patient/Edit.cshtml**

```
@model FaceToFace.Model.User

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>User</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserID)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CodeName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CodeName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CodeName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Device.Name, "Device")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("DeviceID", String.Empty)

        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UseBriefInstructions)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UseBriefInstructions)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UseBriefInstructions)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Thankyou for taking the time to read this, im am new to MVC so i appreciate any help that you can give.

**Update**

With the help of Jason i have started building a viewmodel.  The models i am using in my viewmodel are in a another project i have joined with my solution.

**UserDeviceViewModel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.WebPages.Html;
using FaceToFace.Model;

namespace FaceToFaceWebsite.Models
{
    public class UserDeviceViewModel
    {
        public UserDeviceViewModel()
        {
            User = new User();
            Users = new List<User>();
            Devices = new List<SelectListItem>();
        }

        public User UseBriefInstructions { get; set; }
        public Device Device { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }
        public User CodeName { get; set; }
        public IList<SelectListItem> Devices { get; set; }
        public IList<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**PatientController.cs**

```
namespace FaceToFaceWebsite.Controllers
{
    public class PatientController : Controller
    {
        private F2FData db = new F2FData();

        //
        // GET: /Patient/
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Index(UserDeviceViewModel viewModelDevice)
        {

            var viewModel = new UserDeviceViewModel();

            viewModel.Devices.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "MAU110-10", Value = "1" });
            viewModel.Devices.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "MAU110-100", Value = "2" });
            viewModel.Devices.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "MAU110-101", Value = "3" });
            viewModel.Devices.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "MAU110-102", Value = "4" });
            viewModel.Devices.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "MAU110-103", Value = "5" });

            viewModel.Users.AddRange(db.Users.ToList());

            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

**Views/Patient/Create.cshtml**

```
    @model FaceToFace.Model.User

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    }

    <h2>Create</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <fieldset>
            <legend>User</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CodeName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CodeName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CodeName)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Device.Name, "Device")
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.User.Device.DeviceID, Model.Devices)
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UseBriefInstructions)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UseBriefInstructions)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UseBriefInstructions)
            </div>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    }

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

I will leave out edit to avoid further spam, however I am getting multiple errors now.  I have fixed a few I believe. for the dropdown i am getting this error:

**'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'DropDownListFor' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' has some invalid arguments**

For the `viewModel.Devices.Add` in patient controller i am getting:

**The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection.Add(System.Web.WebPages.Html.SelectListItem)' has some invalid arguments**

along with:

**Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' to 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.SelectListItem'**

and finally below that i am receiving an error from AddRange:

**'System.Collections.Generic.IList' does not contain a definition for 'AddRange' and no extension method 'AddRange' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Any help to get this working would be greatly appreciated. Again, sorry for the spam!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not looks like you are providing the views with a selection of devices to pick from.

Though, overall, I suggest you use a viewmodel approach here. e.g.

**User**

```
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        Device = new Device();
    }

    public int UserID { get; set; }

    public string CodeName { get; set; }

    public bool UseBriefInstructions { get; set; }

    public Device Device { get; set; }
}
```

**Device**

```
public class Device
{
    public int DeviceID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then have a viewmodel class:

```
public class CreatePatientViewModel
{
    public CreatePatientViewModel()
    {
        User = new User();
        Devices = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }

    public User User { get; set; }

    public IList<SelectListItem> Devices { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller, you would use the viewmode like so -

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = new CreatePatientViewModel();

    viewModel.Devices.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Device 1", Value = "1" });
    viewModel.Devices.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Device 2", Value = "2" });

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

The `.Devices` property can then be used to populate the dropdown in the view e.g.

```
@model StackOverflowMvc.Controllers.CreatePatientViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.User.Device.DeviceID, Model.Devices)
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

And when the data is submitted:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index(CreatePatientViewModel viewModel)
{
    // Do whatever you want with the data.
    // viewModel.User.Device.DeviceId will be given the value selected from the dropdown.
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Don't bother with the `[Bind(Include = "UserID,Code....` stuff, it just makes things confusing. The `CreatePatientViewModel` can be used to pick up the values from the submitted form e.g.

`@Html.InputFor(model => model.User.Code)`

In the view, if the above textbox has a value entered, then when a `POST` is made, `CreatePatientViewModel.User.Code` will be passed that value since it matches what `model.User.Code` was used.

Hopefully the above has helped you.

EDIT:

In your controller's `Index` action method, you could do something like:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = new CreatePatientViewModel();

    viewModel.Devices.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Device 1", Value = "1" });
    viewModel.Devices.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Device 2", Value = "2" });

    viewModel.Users.AddRange(db.Users.ToList());

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Change the `CreatePatientViewModel` to include a `Users` property:

```
public class CreatePatientViewModel
{
    public CreatePatientViewModel()
    {
        User = new User();
        Users = new List<User>();
        Devices = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }

    public User User { get; set; }

    public IList<SelectListItem> Devices { get; set; }

    public IList<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Note that I'm assuming your db.Users list is a list of `User` objects, if it's not then simply change that to whatever type it should be.

Comment: Thankyou Jason! In the Controller, its under Public ActionResult Index. Is this to replace the current index ActionResult, can i make another one to go above it, or would it go in the Post for the Create ActionResult?

Thankyou again for your help, its really appreciated.

Comment: I am unable to get this to work because im not sure where i should be putting the information you have provided in the PatientController.

Comment: Thankyou again, i dont have much experience with viewModels and it's telling me my new viewmodel does not contain a definition for CodeName (a part of the User model)  how would i remedy that?

Comment: I am also getting a no definition for "AddRange", not too sure why thats happening either.

Comment: im not sure if this makes a difference but the models User and Device are a part of another project which i have brought into my solution.

Comment: To fix the `AddRange` problem, add the following to the top of the `.cs` file `using System.Collections.Generic`. That is where the function `AddRange` can be found.

Comment: Thankyou Jason, I am already using System.Collections.Generic;  though.  I fixed the CodeName issue by adding a reference to the model project in my web project.  For the Add name i am getting "Error 11 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<FaceToFace.Model.User>' does not contain a definition for 'AddRange' and no extension method 'AddRange' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<FaceToFace.Model.User>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: I think there is an assembly you need to add a reference to called `System.Collections`. Go to the project references and add that assembly. I think that should do it.

Comment: That's odd 'System.Collections' is not in the reference manager.

Comment: For the **viewModel.Devices.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "MAU110-10", Value = "1" });** in Patient Controller im getting the error **The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<System.Web.WebPages.Html.SelectListItem>.Add(System.Web.WebPages.Html.SelectListItem)' has some invalid arguments**

Comment: Thankyou for your help so far, and sorry for the spam.

Comment: No problem. I haven't been able to respond much due to work commitments. I hope at least some of my advise has helped you.

Comment: Thats fine, thankyou for you help so far.  Im not too familiar with the etiqette here so would i be better off asking a new question as im pretty stuck at the moment?

Comment: Best to ask a new question. My core answer of using SelectListItems does solve your original question. For any more things you are struggling with, better to ask a new question.